# How to send two messages (second message with delay, punchline)

Tags: javascript, bots, delay

I'm trying to create a jokebot in js that sends a punchline after a delay.

Here's the code that I'm working with. It only sends me the punchline atm.
I've cut some code out as it's repetetive for the issue.

```
var delayInMilliseconds = 1500;

function poolJoke() {
  const rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 7) + 1;
  if (rand === 1) {
    bot.postMessageToChannel(
      'bots',
      'What does bread loaves say when they greet each other?',
      setTimeout(function() {
        bot.postMessageToChannel('bots',
                                 'Gluten tag.')
      }, delayInMilliseconds),
      params
    );
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you need to add a local variable and clean time, try this code

```
function poolJoke(val) {
    var timer;
    const rand = val;

    if (rand == 1) {
        window.clearTimeout(timer);
      console.log('What does bread loaves say when they greet each other?');
        timer = setTimeout(function () {
            console.log('bots', 'Gluten tag.' + timer)
        }, 5000);
    } 
}
```

Try this solution i tested and work fine:

```
  bot.on("start", function() {

      bot.postMessageToChannel(channel, "Hello world!");
      console.log("Hello world!");

      setTimeout(() => {
            bot.postMessageToChannel(channel,'after 5000 ms.')
        }, 5000)

  });
```

Comment: This works for the console, but I can't seem to implement it to work with the bot